# How can I get the area of the shadowed octagon in the image

Tags: geometry, area

First of all, this is just a problem sent by a friend, I have an idea of how to calculate it's area but I'm not entirely sure if I'm on the right track

[image]

The only data I have is that the area of the small octagon is 63cms^2 and I need to calculate the area of the shadowed area.

I know that to get the area you'll need to subtract the area of the large octagon minus the inner,

It doesn't say but apparently the inner octagon is a regular one, all sides are the same, so I can calculate the width of the inner octagon
$$
    w = (1+√2)s  \text{(s = side)}
$$
and the area formulae 
$$
    2(1+√2)s2
$$
With the width I have the length of the large side of the outer octagon, with the side I have the length of the small side of the outer octagon. is this correct?

With this I can calculate the area of the outer octagon by drawing triangles, using angles and the apothem.

Am I on the right track? how do I keep going if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything that looks like lying on grid points actually does so, then the small octagon is $3\times 3$ unit squares minus $4$ triangles and the big octagon is $5\times 5$ unit squares minus $4$ corner triangles. Then the difference is $16$ unit squares. From the given, we conlclude that one unit square is $9\,\text{cm}^2$. So, ...

Comment: I see your logic, after drawing it, it kinda makes sense.

Comment: Hagen, after I draw I get 4 rectangles and one square, how do you end up with 3x3 unit squares?